# How to display error message in front end using vue js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

This is my error message:

```
     {message: "This username is already taken", status: false, error-type: 3, x-debug: [,…]}
```

My vue js code is

```
 <script>
      regBox = new Vue({
el: "#regBox",
  data: {
   username : '',
   phone : '',
   email : '',
   password: '',
   confirm_password : ''
  },
  methods: {
     handelSubmit: function(e) {
           data = {};
           data['username'] = this.username;
           data['email'] = this.email;
           data['phone'] = this.phone;
           data['password'] = this.password;
           data['confirm_password'] = this.confirm_password;
            $.ajax({
              url: 'https://herokuapp.com/api/user/reg/',
              data: data,
              type: "POST",
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(e) {
              if (e.status)
               alert("Registration Success")
              else {
                alert("failed to Register!");
              }
          }
            });
            return false;
}
},
});
</script>
```

My HTML code is showing below. This is the HTML code I am used to inputting the values from the user. So, how can I display the error messages from the backend?

```
 <div class="tab-pane" id="Registration">
                            <form id="regBox" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" onSubmit="return false;" data-parsley-validate="true" v-on:submit="handelSubmit($event);">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                    Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                     <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required="required" v-model="username" data-parsley-minlength="4"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                    Email</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" v-model="email" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="mobile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                    Mobile</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input name="phone" type="number" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" data-parsley-pattern="^\d{10}$" required="required" v-model="phone"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                    Password</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" v-model="password"/>
                                </div>   
                            </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="confirmpassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                    Confirm Password</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input name="confirm_password" type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Password" required="required" v-model="confirm_password"/>
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

Can anybody tell how to display that error message, For each input, I am getting error messages . So please help how to display the same?

Answer (score 5):

This is how to place the response in your data:

```
handelSubmit: function(e) {
      var self = this;
      data = {};
      data['username'] = this.username;
      data['email'] = this.email;
      data['phone'] = this.phone;
      data['password'] = this.password;
      data['confirm_password'] = this.confirm_password;
      $.ajax({
          url: 'https://herokuapp.com/api/user/reg/',
          data: data,
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (msg, status) {
              self.errors.username = JSON.stringify(msg).replace(/\"/g, "");
          }
      });
}
```

Just place the returned errors in your vue data and [conditionally render](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) the errors when needed like below:

```js
regBox = new Vue({
  el: "#regBox",
  data: {
    username: 'Timmy',
    phone: '0123456789',
    email: 'Timmy@something.com',
    password: 'secret',
    confirm_password: 'secret',
    errors: {
        username: '',
        phone: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handelSubmit: function(e) {
      var self = this;
      data = {};
      data['username'] = this.username;
      data['email'] = this.email;
      data['phone'] = this.phone;
      data['password'] = this.password;
      data['confirm_password'] = this.confirm_password;
      // Ajax call
      var response = { errors: {} };
      response.errors.username = { message: "This username is already taken", status: false, errorType: 3, xDebug: '[,…]'};
      this.errors.username = JSON.stringify(response.errors.username).replace(/\"/g, "");
    }
  },
});
```

```css
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane" id="Registration">
  <form id="regBox" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" onSubmit="return false;" data-parsley-validate="true" v-on:submit="handelSubmit($event);">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required="required" v-model="username" data-parsley-minlength="4" />
        <p class="error" v-if="errors.username">{{ errors.username }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" v-model="email" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="mobile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mobile</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input name="phone" type="number" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" data-parsley-pattern="^\d{10}$" required="required" v-model="phone" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" v-model="password" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="confirmpassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input name="confirm_password" type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Password" required="required" v-model="confirm_password" />
      </div>

    </div>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Click the submit button to see in action.

Comment: {message: "This username is already taken", status: false, error-type: 3, x-debug: [,…]}  How can I display this error message using vue js? I havn't used vue js before

Comment: @Wanderer You want to display an object as a string?

Comment: i just needed to print that meesage inside that "this username is already taken"

Comment: @Wanderer You can use JSON.stringify(), I've updated the answer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: my actual problem is THE FOLLOWING IS THE RESPONSE I GET FROM SERVER. {message: "This username is already taken", status: false, error-type: 3, x-debug: [,…]}

Comment: So, actually how can i get that dynamically

Comment: Just use the `JSON.stringify()` on the ajax response and save it in `this.errors.username` like my example?

Comment: @Wanderer I added a handelSubmit snippet at the top of my answer on how to catch the ajax call.

Comment: @Wanderer You will need to be more specific if you want us to help you.

Comment: @Wanderer @Wouter I think the desired result is to just display the error message without the rest of the response, if that's true, you only need to change one line in the example above to make it work: `this.errors.username = response.errors.username.message; //JSON.stringify(response.errors.username).replace(/\"/g, "");`